# Scrolling Image inside Image Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, photoshop, coreldraw

I have an image of mobile so when i scroll inside image . the content in image should scroll up and down.. I know i have to place a long image inside mobile image so i could see changing on scroll. how to do this ..  If any library or software please tell me 
thanks 
If u don't get question please write comment
...................................
................................................................
................................................................................

Comment: if you could post an example of the desired behavior and your code, that would help the community a lot in helping you find your solution.

Comment: i dont have a code i want to add this image on my site so user can also scroll inside image

Comment: @Dev give your body tag your desired height, you can scroll how you want.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know what you mean by 'scroll inside the image'. Do you have an example? Maybe a different website or something?

Comment: suppose u have a image of mobile ..when you scroll on mobile (image) the content of mobile scrolls up and down..like u use a mobile..but i want it on image

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I Still can't understand your question. Is this the answer you need?

```html
<html lang="en">
    <style>
      .image{
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: auto;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2068958.jpg" alt="myImage">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```